# Is it better/more efficient to use min-width or max-width when designing for desktops/tablets/smartphones

Tags: media-queries, css

I've been in the midst of creating a website, and I want to start using media queries. I want to target desktops, tablets, and smartphones. I'm just learning media queries, and wanted guidence in whether to use min-width or max-width. I've noticed that HTML5Boilerplate uses this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {    }
```

But I've found it easier to use max-width, like so:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 481px) {    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {    }
```

**Is there a real benefit to doing it with min-width, as opposed to max-width?** For some reason I'm just having a hard time getting my head around how to best do it using min-width. Max-width seems to make more sense to me when starting this off. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any benefit in using `min-width` vs `max-width`. If you know how long will be the content then just use the width according to that, that is, you don't need min or max width. However, if you're querying it and you don't know how long will be the content, just try to predict it. I would use `min-width` when I know that there is a possibility for the content being shorter than what I planned so that the layout would not be disrupted. On the other hand, when you know that the content will be a long one, just use max-width.

Answer (score 0):

min-width and max width use for different resolution devices. supposed you don't define any particular device width how was the show the layout....